# Blender 2.8 View Layers - "Exclude" feature

Tags: render-layers, viewlayers

Does anyone know where the "Exclude" and "Mask"-features can be found for the View Layers, (formerly "Render Layers") in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 8):

Old "Render Layers" are now here, in the top right corner:

[image]

In the context menu (RMB) in outliner you can set to any collection to be Excluded, masked (now *holdout*) or hided (now *Indirect Only*).

[image]

*View layer* -> *Set Exclude* is old Exclude function

*View layer* -> *Set Holdout* is old Mask function

*View layer* -> *Set Indirect Only* is like you Hide layer, but not exclude it.

Comment: But there is problem that it can not be combined. For example Holdout without influence another layer. It can be done with Mask and Exclude in old Blender.

Comment: @Cenda it seems to me that realization of layers is almost same. Maybe you can provide an example that do you mean, in new question?

Comment: I mean this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120822/blender-2-8-exclude-and-mask-layer-together