# In Blender 2.8, can a object be both masked (Holdout) and Exclude for a given View Layer?

Tags: rendering, render-layers, masking

It seems that Blender 2.8 doesn't support Mask & Exclude together. It is important in motion graphic for example. Or I am overlooked something?

I know that I can turn off indirect contributions from the object properties, but that would be a problem, because I need to use the same object on another layer.

Blender 2.79 (object is masked and excluded)

[image: Blender 2.79]
Blender 2.80 (object is masked, but can not be excluded together)

[image: Blender 2.80]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a version of Blender still in development.

Comment: how did you manage to perform a mask like the picture you attached to the EEVEE 2.8 Blender? Thanks [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whvsp.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can now use Object passes in the Compositor, created through the Cryptomatte options in the ViewLayer properties.

In the Compositor, three "CryptoObject" socket will be available, that are transformed to a mask (matte) through the "Cryptomatte" node <sup>[announcement & demo](https://youtu.be/55Tg2T0jEzY?t=1269)</sup>.

You can then render a Render Layer without the object altogether, and another one with the object, that you will use only to create the matte.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me that it is a bug. You can post a bug report when it will be open for reporting non-crash staff (it will be after beta-release)