# Masking footage over 3d objects in Blender 2.8+?

Tags: tracking, masking, compositing-nodes, layers, viewlayers

I don't get how to make a mask and use it properly. What I'd like know exactly is how to make a mask of a certain area of the footage, keep it tracked to the footage and make the mask layered in front of any 3d mesh.

[image]

**Q:** How do I create a proper mask to place any 3d object behind an element of my footage?

Comment: Related: [Blender 2.8 View Layers - “Exclude” feature](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/117767/78972)

Comment: Related: [In Blender 2.8, can a object be both masked (Holdout) and Exclude for a given View Layer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/120822/78972)

Comment: Until the question gets reopened: Do you mind putting a bit more effort into your question and elaborate on what do you want *exactly*? Just adding a rendering on top of your footage? Including transparency (an alpha channel) while rendering?

Comment: brockman, what I need to know exactly is how to make a mask of a certain area of the footage, keep it tracked to the footage, and make the mask be layered in front of any 3d mesh I put behind it - I don't know how to make a mask and how to layer it

Comment: Hi @HoofMcPoof :) please add any new/ additional information in *the question body text* as an [edit] so that it is easily visible to other users. There are many users who do not read the comments, and comments are not searchable content, thus are will not be found easily by future readers.  Thanks :)

Comment: Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183081/how-to-have-person-in-video-mask-added-geometry-as-they-walk-in-front/183108#183108

Answer (score 3):

Load the background image in the image editor or the movie clip editor.

[image]

Set the editor in mask mode

[image]

On the image, click while pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and draw a mask for the area you want to use as foreground.

[image]

Then in the compositor use that mask to combine the foreground and background elements.

[image]

Comment: To track elements on moving video, you can parent tracking points to the control points of the mask. Do a search on this site for rotoscoping.