# Exclude feature in blender 2.82

Tags: rendering, collections, viewlayers

I can't find the "Set Exclude" feature in 2.82 as shown in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117767/blender-2-8-view-layers-exclude-feature). Did they move it, if so where is it?

Comment: Are you referring to [this *Set Exclude*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117767/blender-2-8-view-layers-exclude-feature)?

Comment: @RobertGützkow yes but I can't find Set Exclude in 2.82.

Comment: Where is that option in 2.82

Comment: This feature was only named *Set Exclude* in the early development of Blender 2.80. I will vote to reopen the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature to exclude a collections from rendering in the view layer was called *Set Exclude* in the early development of Blender 2.80. At least since the release candidates it is called *Exclude from View Layer* and can be set by toggling the checkbox in front of the collection name.

[image: Enabled Collection]

[image: Excluded Collection]

Alternatively it can also be set through the context menu, by right-clicking on the collection and then selecting either *View Layer > Disable from View Layer* or *View Layer > Enable in View Layer*.

[image: Disable Collection in Context Menu]

[image: Enable Collection in Context Menu]

Comment: I need them to interact with each other,  what I mean is. I need to have a shadow on one object while the other object is render on a different render layer. If that make sense.

Comment: @J.Jesse That's an entirely different question though. Currently it sounds to me like you want to use a shadow catcher. Please check if one of the many answers to this topic solves your problem. If you don't find a suitable solution, post a new question that contains a detailed description of what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried already that didn't achieve the desired effect.